# Disable Facebook popup if user already likes my website Facebook page

Tags: facebook

In my website I have put Facebook popup. Now I want only those people to see that pop up who didn't like my website Facebook page yet.

this is my code.

.facebookOuter { background-color:#F4F4F4; width:230px; padding:10px 0 10px 10px; height:250px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; } .facebookInner { height:250px; overflow:hidden; }         (function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

I looking to hear from you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to store a flag somewhere. Guess this might be helpful. Check the link below

[Facebook popup remember when user likes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343687/facebook-popup-remember-when-user-likes)

Comment: do you have any idea where to put that code.suggested by Mr Wernsey.?

Comment: I think you can link that code with facebook like button, inside onclick function.

Comment: ALso this link might be usefull.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe#likes

Comment: If your question has been answered accept my answer or put your own answer and accept it. Happy coding! :)